# Clebsch-Gordan Matrix

Tags: matrices

I found papers (e.g. 'A theory of phase-sensitive rotation invariance with spherical harmonic and moment-based representations') which state the formula:
$$ b^{kl}_f = [F_k \otimes F_l] C_{kl} \widehat{F_i}$$
It says that $C_{kl}$ is the Clebsch-Gordan matrix, however I cant find any unique definition of this term.
Moreover the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients are of the form
$$\langle\ j_1, m_1; j_2, m_2 | J, M, j_1, j_2 \rangle$$
which contain way more then two variables.

What would the matrix $C_{kl}$ would look like, e.g. $C_{3,2}$?